# Write file stream during file upload - node.js & node-formidable

Tags: node.js, file-upload

Clients can upload files by using a Multi-part form post to my node.js application. To handle the file upload I'm using the node-formidable library.

Now, I manage to upload the file in chunks to node but I don't want it to be buffered before it's written to disk. So, I'm trying to understand how I can write the file data chunks to disk when they're received. I don't fully understand the node-formidable api how to acheive.

Can someone give a simple example of how to listen for an incoming file, create a file stream and then access the data coming in and write that data to the stream and finally closing the stream.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

There is one example [here](http://www.componentix.com/blog/13). It doesn't use formidable library but a similar module (multipart). But it explains everything that you have asked for. You can massage it to fit you needs.

Thanks,
KA

Comment: I'm afraid it's not enough. I don't understand how to convert it to formidable. What I'm doing now is that I'm overriding the "form.onPart". When a new part is detected I'm creating a writeStream and add a listener for "data". When new data comes in I'm writing that to the stream. It works but I want to know if that's the correct way of doing it. That's why I would like a complete simple example.

Comment: @exkoria there's no other way of doing it, and overriding `form.onPart` is documented that way, so i think you're on the right track.